# Find out what gems to install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

How can you find out what gems you need to put in your Gemfile?  I know you can run bundle show, but that only shows the next gem to install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your gemfile is just a list of libraries your software depends on. Running bundled produces a Gemfile.lock which further specifies which versions of each gem you installed. This makes it easy to recreate your application environment wherever you go or however large your team is.

As to what to put in it, whatever you need for your project. A rails project includes rails, SQLite, jquery, etc. you can ad whatever else you need

Need authentication? Devise or Authlogic will do. Front end toolkit? Twitter-bootstrap-rails will do that. Testing? Rspec-rails or cucumber-rails will help you out there

Comment: Is there a way to find out what version you should use and what order they should be instaled in?

Comment: Your only tied to a specific version if you are integrating into another project. In most cases for a new project you don't need to be concerned